# How to swipe left to right to navigate back in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I make a transition back to previous screen on swipe from left to right in a specific screen?

Comment: which navigation library you've used? In case `react-navigation`, you can take a look here `https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#gesturesenabled`

Comment: that worked! thank you! just had to add `gestureDirection: 'inverted'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `@react-navigation/native-stack`, you may want to use `@react-navigation/stack`. Because in `@react-navigation/stack` comes with swipe back and you don't need to make any configuration.

> one note from [reactnavigation.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) : One thing to keep in mind is that while @react-navigation/stack is extremely customizable, it's implemented in JavaScript. While it runs animations and gestures using natively, the performance may not be as fast as a native implementation. This may not be an issue for a lot of apps, but if you're experiencing performance issues during navigation, consider using @react-navigation/native-stack instead - which uses native navigation primitives.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use [react-native-swipe-gestures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures) and you can write your function to go back on swiping left to right

```
onSwipeLeft(gestureState) {
     // your function to go back
  }
```